# Error on upgrading to flutter 3 : Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I recently upgraded to flutter 3 and can't build android applications.

I get the below error

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_jailbreak_detection:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20.
> Required by:
> project :flutter_jailbreak_detection
> > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - gradle70JavadocElements
> - gradle70RuntimeElements
> - gradle70SourcesElements
> - gradle71JavadocElements
> - gradle71RuntimeElements
> - gradle71SourcesElements
> - javadocElements
> - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
> - sourcesElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           14.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA %
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA %
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA %
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA %
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA %
elm@MakamuEvanss-MacBook-Pro Rwanda-NCBA % flutter build apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_jailbreak_detection:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20.
> Required by:
> project :flutter_jailbreak_detection
> > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - gradle70JavadocElements
> - gradle70RuntimeElements
> - gradle70SourcesElements
> - gradle71JavadocElements
> - gradle71RuntimeElements
> - gradle71SourcesElements
> - javadocElements
> - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
> - sourcesElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.0' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'gradle71SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.plugin.api-version '7.1' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'library' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' and found compatible value '8'.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' and found compatible value 'jar'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
> - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but no value provided.
> - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_jailbreak_detection' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I've tried flutter clean, Invalidated cache, pub get/upgade/upgrade but still the error persists

Comment: I was about to say flutter pub upgrade and flutter clean & cache repair until i saw your last comment. If you haven't got any modifications in android, maybe delete the folder and regenerate android source.

Comment: @Srikanth how do i regenerate android source?

Comment: delete the android folder and do a `flutter create .` from the project folder.